# Xamarin - How do i get data binding string value from an ImageCell in a listview when tapped?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am still fresh into Xamarin, I am having an issue with figuring out how I will get the Binding value of an image cell.

I have a list view using ImageCell as shown below, iv'e set the itemSelected command to the listview named "selectedBox_Tapped"

> ```
>     <Grid>
>         <ListView x:Name="itemListView" ItemSelected="selectedBox_Tapped">
>             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}"
>                         Detail="{Binding Compound}"
>                                ImageSource="defaultImage.png">
>                     </ImageCell>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>         </ListView>
>     </Grid>
> ```

in the C# code behind, I'm attempting this

> ```
>     private async void selectedBox_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
>     {
>         string name = ????
>
>         await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(name));
>     }
> ```

I Would like to be able to get the string value of the {Binding Name} from the ImageCell and then pass it to my DetailsPage as a constructor as shown above.

where **String name = ????** I cannot figure out what I need to do to make this work.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ItemTappedEventArgs`

```
private async void selectedBox_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
{
    // args.Item will be the context of the tapped cell
    // you will need to cast it to the correct class
    var item = (MyClass)args.Item;

    // once item is cast, you can just refer to its properties
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(item.Name));
}
```